# Accidentally removed binutils linker (/usr/bin/ld)

Tags: 14.04, shared-library

I have accidentally removed the file `/usr/bin/ld` and now I can't compile my C programs any more.

How can I re-install the linker from the repositories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ld` is the linker --- it is in package `binutilus`. You can find it using

```
[romano:~] % apt-file search -F /usr/bin/ld
binutils: /usr/bin/ld
```

You can reinstall it by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall binutils
```

Comment: If it solved your problem, then please mark it as an answer for future reference for others.

Comment: @user3326918, please read http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers --- Thanks.